# Cloudflare CDN and JavaScript deployment

Tags: performance, caching, cdn, cloudflare

I need to deploy my JavaScript files multiple times a day for a complex (rich) Web application.

CloudFlare caches the static resources. So if you update them you need to either purge the cache or turn the development mode on.

Should I use services like CloudFlare for a constantly updating web app. If not, what CDN service should I use?

Comment: What is the primary reason for wanting to use CloudFlare? Speed or ability to avoid a total blackout in cases of DoS etc.? If you're looking for speed increases, I would try Varnish first.

Comment: I suggest giving Varnish a try first and see if you're happy with any possible improvements, you can purge the cache manually yourself very easily whenever needed (you can also compress your assets with Varnish btw, instead of burdening your server with doing that for static assets). Personally I'd only use CloudFlare if I was willing to spend $200/mo. on the Business plan, to get access to Railgun.

Comment: Varnish seems good, but I was looking for a thirdparty solution so that I wouldn't need to manage it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when you deploy your js files, are you deploying a whole new application on your server or simply just replacing js files (hot swap?)

If it's the former case, then one approach you can go is to append some sort of timestamp at the end of your js files, such as myJavaSript-1000100100.js. And every time you push a new deployment, the numbers will get changed, so you won't be affected by the old cached js files.

However, if hot swap is what you are talking about, there is no better way to handle it but through manual cache or header settings.

If you are techy enough, it should be straightforward to write some short program to send a purge request everytime you update your js file. Otherwise, you need to login into whatever your CDN service provider and do it from there.

The other option is set a relatively short cache-control header. If you update your file every couple of hours, you can set the max-age to be 1hour or 30mins, in this case, after your specified time, the cache will automatically being refreshed by your browser. However, this does comes at a price that you may encounter old files between your new deployment and the file get refreshed.

Comment: I was also thinking of sending a purge request every time I update my js application (which is multiple times a day). But CloudFlare says you should NOT frequently purge the cache -- it affects performance.

Comment: Well what CloudFlare claimed is true, but don't you agree correctness is more important than performance? Meanwhile, you are only purging those files you need to replace, not all the files, which is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I usually append a query parameter to the URI to my javascript files based on the timestamp the files were generated.  My build script for my javascript files (which happens to be Dojo) outputs a file called `cachebust` which contains a short timestamp, like `20230321` (the current date at time of writing).  The web page that is going to require the javascript then requires it, appending `?t=20230321` (obviously it reads that string from the `cachebust` file).  CDNs like Cloudflare recognise the query parameter as part of the URL being requested, and so yesterday's deployment of https://my.server.com/foo/bar/file.js?t=20230320 is a completely different entity in their cache to today's deployment of https://my.server.com/foo/bar/file.js?t=20230321 and so there is no need to clear the cache or rename the javascript file `file.js`.

Comment: https://developers.cloudflare.com/automatic-platform-optimization/reference/query-parameters/

I may have misread this but it looks as though a URL query tells cloudflare NOT to server the cached content by default.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/automatic-platform-optimization/reference/page-rule-integration/

This suggests you need to configure a page rule "Cache Level: Cache Everything" which WILL go tot the cache for file paths with URL queries.

Comment: Hmm good point @plumpNation, it looks like any non-whitelisted query param, including my "?t=1234", would always bypass the cache, which is not the behaviour I intended.  However, that doc is about APO, which I don't think we used.  I seem to recall that the headers reaching the browser indicate whether the cache was hit or not, and all looked good to me.  Since then I have stopped using Cloudflare (we would get weird error responses that I never figured out, reporting that our server had returned a 5xx response when it hadn't) so I'm not in a position to look into it further.